# How can I write the output of Select-String in powershell without the line numbers?

Tags: powershell, select-string

I am using powershell to filter a textfile using a regular expression. To do that I am using the following command:
`Select-String -Pattern "^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}[a-z]{5}" -CaseSensitive rockyou.txt > filter.txt`
The issue however, when writing them to filter.txt it's preceding the matched strings with the name of the original file followed by the line numbers e.g.:

rockyou.txt:12345:abcdefg

rockyou.txt:12345:abcdefg

rockyou.txt:12345:abcdefg

How can I make it so that it ommits the line numbers?

Comment: Pipe it. something like ```Select-String -Pattern "^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}[a-z]{5}" -CaseSensitive rockyou.txt | $_.split(":")[-1] | Out-File(filter.txt)```

Comment: Wouldn't a matching string be something like `01ABcdefg`?

Answer (score 2):

`Select-String` outputs an object per match, and each has a `Line` property containing the original line in which the match occurred. You can grab only the `Line` value, like so:

```
... |Select-String ... |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line |Out-File filter.txt
```

Comment: This...just because it looks like a string once formatted doesn't mean it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

This way seems to work.  Set-content saves the string version of the matchinfo object without any extra blank lines, as opposed to out-file or ">".

```
get-content rockyou.txt | select-string '^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}[a-z]{5}' -ca | 
  set-content filter.txt
get-content filter.txt

01ABcdefg
```

It occurred to me you might still want the filename:

```
select-string '^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}[a-z]{5}' rockyou.txt -ca | 
  % { $_.filename + ':' + $_.line } > filter.txt
cat filter.txt

rockyou.txt:01ABcdefg
```